# Como conseguir que mi aplicación publique un tweew con un mensaj predeterminado

Tags: java, twitter

Hace poco que he aprendido un poco de Java y quería saber como puedo hacer para que cuando ocurra algo, no solo lo  notifique al dispositivo del usuario, si no a su twitter poniendo un tweet. Igual esto es demasiado complejo, pero me gustaría una pequeña orientación.

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask], de paso también realizar el [tour], para que de este modo comprendas mejor de que va SO en español; una vez hecho lo anterior por favor edita y coloca lo que llevas hecho o investigado y las dudas puntuales que tienes.

Comment: Puedes utilizar muchas libreíaas para integrar tu aplicación con el servicio de Twitter, por ejemplo tienes la twitter4J (http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) y también puedes encontrar miles de ejemplos y guias como la siguiente de codepedia (https://www.codepedia.org/ama/how-to-post-to-twittter-from-java-with-twitter4j-in-10-minutes/)